# what is returned by Engine_Api::_()->getTable

Tags: socialengine

I wonder if it is an array that is returned by calling getTable('tbl', 'module') or an object. I am facing problems when I try to insert the returned value into another array and then encode it as JSON. Passing it per se to `$this->_helper->json()` generates JSON output successfully, but using it as part of another array just does not work and is a null array. See below for the controller code:

```
//put your code here
public function indexAction () {

}

public function browseAction () {

    $resultArray = $this->prepareArray();

    $this->sendResponse($resultArray);
}

    /**
 * HTTP Response Codes
 */
const HTTP_OK = 200;

public function sendResponse($data) {
    ob_clean();
    $this->_helper->json($data);
}

public function prepareArray() {
    //Here we will prepare the array to be later encoded as JSON
    $responseArray = [
        'status_code' => '',
        'body'       => [
            'itemsCount' => '',
            'foods' =>  [
                'food_id' => '',
                'food_title' => '', 
                'image' => '',
            ],
        ],
    ];

    $foodTable = Engine_Api::_()->getDbTable('foods', 'restapi');

    $foods = $foodTable->getFoods($this->view);
    $foodArray = [];
    print_r($foods);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($foods)) {
        $foodArray['food_id'] = $row['food_id'];
        $foodArray['food_title'] = $row['title'];
        $foodArray['image'] = $row['image'];  
    }

                error_log( $row ['food_id'] . ',' . $row['title']);            

    $responseArray['status_code'] = '200';
    $responseArray['body']['itemsCount'] = count($foods);        
    $responseArray['body']['foods']= $foodsArray;
    return $responseArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is set properly, `getTable('tbl', 'module')` returns `object(Module_Model_DbTable_Tbl)`. This is the model of your database table.

Your particular error is on the line where you're assigning `foodsArray` variable that isn't defined anywhere. You should have assign `foodArray` here instead.

`$responseArray['body']['foods']= $foodsArray; // should be foodArray`

Comment: Hi. How can I contact you?

Comment: @JasonStack kirk@kirk.kh.ua